# openssh keep on asking for password even correct (Ubuntu and Debian)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, ssh

I had installed openssh server on both my Ubuntu and Debian pc following this guide : https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-openssh-server/ and previously they work fine, but after some weeks they keep on asking for password and terminate after some attemps, i have use the ssh -vv root@ip to debug and they give me these information :

```
debug1: Host '192.168.6.17' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/group/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug2: bits set: 2081/4096
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/group/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/group/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/group/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/group/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/group/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/group/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/group/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/group/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
Password:
Connection closed by 192.168.6.17 port 22
```

Hope someone can tell me what i messed up

Comment: You are logging in as the root user. This is a potential security concern, so there is a `PermitRootLogin` in the `sshd_config` file that can be set to `no` or `yes`. You should check that. As far as I can see, the tutorial doesn't even mention _configuring the server_, so you're left with the default settings. These could differ depending on packaging. This is not an answer because it may be pointing in the wrong direction.  You may also want to check the corresponding server log entries on the server (somewhere under `/var/log`).

Comment: @Kusalananda is right. Also, check the permissions on the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on server-side. If permissions are too permissive, then `sshd` won't accept using this file since it may represents a security threat (you should `chmod 600` to be sure).

Comment: Yes, I checked the configuration file and it seems like I have changed the configuration, now the problem solves, thank you very much